# cmd System cannot find file

Tags: copy, cmd

I have a very weird resule in cmd, the current folder is test :

```
c:\test>
```

with

```
c:\test\>dir
10/04/2013  18:06    <REP>          10042013
```

in the folder test I've put a exe : oggenc.exe

```
c:\test\>copy oggenc.exe 10042013
```

Although when I do a copy the system tells me it cannot find the specified file

I really can't understand what's going wrong, can you please help me ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
xcopy /h oggenc.exe 10042013
```

Does the trick, my file was hidden that's why copy couldn't do the job, problem solved, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `c:\test\copy` isn't an executable. `copy` is.

Comment: Ah- you've edited the question. So - could you show us a DIR listing of the c:\test directory, please?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have the appropriate permissions. In my test case I was able to create a folder "C:\test" but not copy my own %userprofile% into "C:\test"

when I opened the cmd as administrator it worked just fine!

I tried to post a picture but apparently don't have a high enough rep yet. sorry.

here is a link to the picture instead
http://bit.ly/1ubwjY4